# Rails 4: assets on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have deployed my app to heroku, but some assets are not loading, e.g.:

- GET https://myapp.herokuapp.com/javascripts/s3_direct_upload.js - 404
- GET https://myapp.herokuapp.com/stylesheets/s3_direct_upload_progress_bars.css - 404

the problem is in precompile, I have to add every file manually to assets.rb
but I don't really want to do it, because there are many of them

in my assets.rb I tried:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile << Proc.new { |path|
  if path =~ /\.(css|js)\z/
    full_path = Rails.application.assets.resolve(path).to_path
    app_assets_path = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets').to_path
    if full_path.starts_with? app_assets_path
      puts "including asset: " + full_path
      true
    else
      puts "excluding asset: " + full_path
      false
    end
  else
    false
  end
}
```

and:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile = false
```

but it's not working

I've added to application.rb

```
config.serve_static_files = true
```

also, //=require from my precompilled assets are not included into header

everything works good in dev environment on my laptop

what do I need to change to make it work in production?

**Update**

I use helper, to include some js and css files in views:

```
def javascript(*files)
  content_for(:foot) { javascript_include_tag(*files) }
end
```

and in my view I have:

```
<% stylesheet 's3_direct_upload_progress_bars' %>
<% javascript 's3_direct_upload', 'init.script.js' %>
```

assets from gem s3_direct_upload are not loading
init.script.js is located in assets/javascripts, so it is loading as it should be

another problem, in my application.js I have:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.slicknav.min.js

$(function ()
{
    $('#menu').slicknav();
});
```

after `assets:precompile` it looks okay, but in console I have error:

```
$(...).slicknav is not a function
```

so it was compiled wrong? everything works good in development environment

**Update 2**

Ignore the second problem, I found second require for jquery, it caused this error

but I still can't include assets from gem without precompile,
can I somehow disable this behavior? I just want include some assets for specific actions without headache

Comment: did you run `rake assets:precompile` in your console before deploying to heroku?

Comment: I tried that too, but I include some files with `javascript_include_tag`, so they are not included in precompile

Answer (score 2):

By default **Rails 4** will not serve your assets. To enable this functionality you need to go into **config/application.rb** and add this line:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Alternatively you can achieve the same result by including the rails_12factor gem in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

This gem will configure your application to serve static assets so that you do not need to do this manually in a config file.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: @lasoweq:  For more details please refer this link: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline

Comment: console said `serve_static_assets` is deprecated, I have to use `serve_static_files` instead. Also, I have `rails_12factor` in my Gemfile